# Apache + Node.js + mod_proxy. How to route one domain to :3000 and another to :80

Tags: apache, node.js, mod-proxy

Problem: I need to host a Node-application and a php-application on the same server on different domains.

example.com should use port 80 as normal, but node-example.com should route to port 3000.

Routing ALL traffic from port 80 to 3000 works fine using mod_proxy, thusly:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin info@node-example.com
    ServerName  node-example.com
    ServerAlias www.node-example.com

    ProxyRequests off

    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Location />
            ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/
            ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

This however makes both example.com and node-example.com to point to localhost:3000 and run the Node-app.

Is there a way to keep example.com to point to port 80?

It would also be okay for example.com/old-admin to point to port 80.

Answer (score 39):

Just make two `<VirtualHost *:80>` tags

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin info@node-example.com
    ServerName www.node-example.com

    ProxyRequests off

    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Location />
            ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/
            ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin info@node-example.com
    ServerName  node-example.com    

    ProxyRequests off

    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Location />
            ProxyPass http://localhost:80/
            ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:80/
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

It should work that way ;)

Or if your `localhost:80` app isn't node you can remove `<Proxy *>` & `<Location />` tags for that target and replace it with `DocumentRoot /var/www/node-example.com` - your static path to index.html

Comment: I tried using two virtualhost-tags before, but it wasn't working... Turns out I forgot about setting "NameVirtualHost *". Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: Wow! you saved me from iptables and its invisible rules :) Works great. tnx mate.

Comment: If you still not getting it worked, make sure you have enabled `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_http` in apache configuration and restart the server.

Comment: @drinchev

Do I need to add "ProxyRequests off" to all of my apache site files?

Comment: from the [docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) : Strictly limiting access is essential if you are using a forward proxy (using the ProxyRequests directive). Otherwise, your server can be used by any client to access arbitrary hosts while hiding his or her true identity. This is dangerous both for your network and for the Internet at large. When using a reverse proxy (using the ProxyPass directive with ProxyRequests Off), access control is less critical because clients can only contact the hosts that you have specifically configured.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you create two different virtual host conf files for two domains. This will enable you to configure them independently besides moving them to different servers when the scaling is different.

For apache2 with default installation location,

> create a file in /etc/apache2/sites-available/www.example1.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName  www.example1.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@example1.com

        <Directory /home/example1/api/admin/docs>
                Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
                DirectoryIndex index.html
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/example1/api/mobile/docs>
                Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
                DirectoryIndex index.html
        </Directory>

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On

        ProxyPass /api/         "http://localhost:30007/"
        ProxyPassReverse /      "http://localhost:30007/"

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example1/example1.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example1/example1.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Create another file `www.example2.com.conf` in `sites-available` and copy the above configuration replacing example1 with example2.

For subdomains, replace `www` in filename and inside configuration with your subdomain, eg: `api`.

Once you have the conf files created, you have to enable them with command

`a2ensite www.example1.com.conf`

and then reload apache2 with command

`sudo systemctl reload apache2`

Make sure you have the directories `example1` and `example2` created in APACHE_LOG_DIR created before you reload the apache.

Thats it. configure your domain's A record with server IP address in your domain registrar or CDN, whatever you are using and you should be good to go.