# node.js authentication php auth_user

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, authentication

I want to use node.js for file uploading at my company. The current file uploader they have is a simple html 5 page with a php script backend that is php_auth_user to authenticate. My boss loves the idea of node.js for file upload but is unsure about how we would authenticate / authorize this file uploader.

I have figured out how to forward to my node server from apache at these two sites:

[Apache + Node.js + mod_proxy. How to route one domain to :3000 and another to :80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259321/apache-node-js-mod-proxy-how-to-route-one-domain-to-3000-and-another-to-8)

http://thatextramile.be/blog/2012/01/hosting-a-node-js-site-through-apache

However, I can't figure out how I would access the php_auth_user server variable in my node application.

Any ideas?

Edit:

I am not looking for authentication for node.js. i will be using one of the ldap authentication libraries already out there. What I want is a way for my node server to be able to pick up the php_user_auth and php_user_pwd server variables sent during our pre-existing http basic auth. I will then use those variables to authenticate against the ldap in the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some helpful things I found:

popular authentication for node.js [passport](http://passportjs.org)

node.js modules - [authentication](https://nodejsmodules.org/tags/authorization)

Also this ties together some interesting tech - [orchestrate](http://orchestrate.io/blog/2014/06/26/build-user-authentication-with-node-js-express-passport-and-orchestrate)

This may help you in accessing your PHP authentication variable - [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502031/authenticate-user-for-socket-io-nodejs)

Comment: I realize that node.js has module that handle authentication. My issue is that we don't want a seperate authentication for this application. Our users are already using basic auth to log in and I want to be able to use that username / password entered in to sign into this app.

Comment: @BillGarrison I just added another link that may help. Just edited the last link in my post.

Comment: last link is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @BillGarrison I'm glad that helped! I am getting ready to set up some node.js authentication too.