# nodejs server doesn't respond when clients use vpn or proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, server, centos

i have a simple noedjs server running on port 3001 of my server

im using this nodejs server along side of my website which runs on port 80 via some webserver (not sure what someone else did the configuration  )

you can access my nodejs server here

http://88.198.164.43:3001/

the problem is when clients use vpn or proxy  , nodejs server on port 3001 stops responding
and i get something like

```
ERROR
The requested URL could not be retrieved
The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: http://88.198.164.43:3001/

Access Denied.
```

is there any solution fort this ?

**question 2 solved thanx to @charlietfl comment**

Comment: Use regex in php and return a json response for the js to use. Doing it with eval() is dangerous if somehow malicious code got put in there and is not needed for your use case

Comment: I still able to send a request to your node server with VPN connected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your VPN/Proxy has a firewall integrated, it might just not allow connection to a majority of unusual ports. (3001 isn't usual compared to 80 for example which couldn't be blocked without losing access to every websites in the world)

Your best option to verify this would be to use a reverse proxy, either on apache or nginx to try mapping your 3001 port to a 80 port but on a different url.

Example: `88.198.164.43/node ---proxying---> 88.198.164.43:3001`.

See the config for apache: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52185402/3415561

Or the config for nginx: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10375750/3415561