# cant connect to node server via socket.io after mapping ip:port address to a domain withouth port

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

im very new to nodejs so bare with me

so i have a nodejs server which i use to inject live data to my php/laravel website via socket.io
i run my nodejs server in port 3002 and apache is using port 80

so my node server is running on

http://78.47.222.225:3002

so i noticed clients who use vpn or proxy cant connect to my nodeserver address and websocket connection fails for them

after asking in this question it was suggested its bcuz vpn is fire walling unusual ports

[nodejs server doesn't respond when clients use vpn or proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63649871)

so i maped a address to 3002 port , so basically

http://example.com/server ---proxying---> http://78.47.222.225:3002

so now when i go to `http://example.com/server` i get

```
Hello World!
```

which means its working but in my homepage `http://example.com`  when i try to connect to the server via socket.io it fails ... homepage source

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js" ></script>

</head>
<body>
<script>

    const  socket = io.connect("http://example.com/server" ,  {transports:['websocket']});

    socket.on('connect', function () {
        
        console.log('connected!!!') ; 
        
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

not sure why is this happening but in my console i see it trying to connect to this address

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://example.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 301
r.doOpen @ index.js:83
```

but shouldn't it try the `example.com/server/socket.io` ? considering i gave `http://example.com/server` to io.connect ?

it works fine when i try connecting via ip:port ... try this address to connect via ip:port instead of proxy address

http://example.com?port=1

```
const  socket = io.connect("http://78.47.222.225:3002" ,  {transports:['websocket']});

socket.on('connect', function () {
    
    console.log('connected!!!') ; 
    
});
```

---

basically

```
io.connect("http://example.com/server")
```

tries to connect to

```
ws://example.com/socket.io
```

which will fail even tho server works with this address `example.com/server` ... i think it should connect to `ws://example.com/server/socket.io` ?

but

```
io.connect("http://78.47.222.225:3002")
```

will connect to

```
ws://78.47.222.225:3002/socket.io
```

and it works !

proxy setting

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443 >
.....
.....

<Location /server>
            ProxyPass http://localhost:3002/
            ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3002/
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: please share your apache proxy settings

Comment: @Chandan i've added the setting

Comment: Can you please add your whole config ? Also how/why do you proxy that/this: `http://bia2roll.com/server` to a public ip: `http://78.47.222.225:3002`. Regardingless, take a look here on the "path" option: https://socket.io/docs/server-api/

Comment: @hretic try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526281/websockets-and-apache-proxy-how-to-configure-mod-proxy-wstunnel

Comment: @Marc whats wrong with proxy-ing address to public ip ? if your asking why im doing it as i explained in the question is to avoid getting blocked by vpn users

Comment: @Chandan pleas post it as answer so i can accept it

Comment: @hretic I have posted it as answer - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to problem with your proxy settings:

You can try this: [WebSockets and Apache proxy : how to configure mod_proxy_wstunnel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526281/websockets-and-apache-proxy-how-to-configure-mod-proxy-wstunnel)

Answer (score 1):

Your proxy setting indicates a VHost on port 443, which is default port for SSL.

But your requests with `bia2roll.com` are unsecure (http:// or ws://).

Secure your server by adding SSL (Let's encrypt) and call it with https or wss
or
Unsecure your server by binding on the port 80